# Sending mail from localhost doesn't work as expected

Tags: python, linux, smtp, mailer

I'm trying to send a message from `localhost:1025`. I'm running an SMTP debug server using this command `python -m smtpd -n localhost:1025`.

Here is the code used for sending the mail:

```
msg = mailer.Message(From='noreply@'+company['host'],
                         To=req['mail'],
                         Subject='E-mail confirmation',
Body=Template(open('./confirmation.html').read()).render(company=company, account=account, accode=accode))
mailer.Mailer(company['host'], port=1025).send(msg)
```

The `req['mail']` contains my email address, when I checked my email inbox and spam folders, I didn't find any message - What's, supposedly, caused this problem?

Answer (score 4):

As is made quite clear [in the documentation](https://docs.python.org/2/library/smtpd.html#debuggingserver-objects) the debugging server does not attempt to deliver email messages. This is to allow testing and verification of the email's content without actually sending any mail.

Comment: I missed that, thanks for your answer. But even after running the server using `python -m smtpd -n localhost:1025` - the message doesn't get sent. Do you have any idea?

Comment: The `PureServer` class needs to be told where to deliver. From `python -m smtpd --help` it seems that by default it will use port 25 on the local host as its attempted delivery point. Is there a local SMTP server running?

Comment: I have already installed exim. But after running `python -m smtpd -n -c PureServer localhost:25` I get "AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'PureServer'".

Comment: Even after starting the exim server and running `python -m smtpd -n -c localhost:25` - no message gets sent.

Comment: I'd recommend you configure your mails to deliver to a known-good SMTP server at this stage before wasting too much time configuring local sendmail services.